# Basic understanding of stress tensors in a fluid

Tags: tensor-calculus, fluid-dynamics

So, after having spent the last 9 hours attempting to understand the basic tenets of stress tensors in fluids, I can honestly say that I think I know less now than when I began.

My questions are these: what precisely is a stress tensor in the context of fluid dynamics, and why is it the case that stress tensors are necessarily symmetric in this context?

One of the resources I found referred to the entries of the stress tensor matrix as being the representations of the directional stresses on an infinitesimal cube in a flow, supposing that this cube of fluid is static.  This would explain the symmetry of the tensor (since the fluid cube is not rotating, the shear stresses would have to be equal in magnitude at the corners), but it would also indicate to me that the perpendicular forces (the diagonal elements of the tensor) must all be zero, since the particle is also not translating in the fluid.  I know this is incorrect, but why?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the Physics Stack Exchange, since you're looking for a proper physical interpretation of the components of the stress tensor. (There obviously is mathematics here, but that's not primarily what you seem to be after...)

Comment: @semiclassical I thought that might be the case.  I posted here since I myself am in mathematics and I thought the physicist explanation might utilize material I'm wholly unfamiliar with.

Comment: It's definitely a judgment call as to which Stack Exchange this is most suitable for; I leaned towards Physics simply because you seemed to be focusing on interpreting the forces specifically. But if you're looking for an discussion that isn't _too_ physics havy, I can see why you leaned to here instead.

Comment: @Semiclassical I went ahead and cross-posted it over to Physics.  Can't hurt to get a couple perspectives.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Basic understanding of stress tensors in a fluid](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134969/basic-understanding-of-stress-tensors-in-a-fluid). For future reference, we generally [discourage cross-posting between sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @ChrisWhite I wasn't aware of that rule. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.